# Can PCA be applied to multivariate time-series for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: time-series, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm applying PCA for dimensionality reduction of a multivariate time-series data with >100 dimensions. I was wondering if there are any short comings to this approach when working with time-series data. If so, what are some other approaches that can be applied in order to carry out the task of dimensionality reduction?